# Magento store blank screen after domain change

Tags: magento, dns, screen, switch-statement

After attempting to *change the domain for a Magento Store* (Ver 1.4.1.1), I am presented with a blank screen on the frontend. The site has not been moved, only a domain change.

On the backend (admin panel), it does allow me to login, however, once in the panel, all i get is the upper header with the menu options and the footer. However, even after clicking through the admin options loads. The content area is absolutely blank.

There has been no error reports thus far, and after going through several forums these have been my unsuccessful attempts at solving the issue:

**1.**...Checked the local.xml file for the db connection.

**2.**...In the DB, under core_config_data i have pointed the new domain for secure and unsecure

**3.**...Increased memory size in the htaccess

**4.**...I've enabled php error logging in the .htaccess like so:

```
    php_flag  log_errors on
    php_value error_log  /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
```

And the error output was a 500 Internal Server Error

**5.**..In index.php I have changed this line

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '';
```

to this one

```
$mageRunCode = isset($_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE']) ? $_SERVER['MAGE_RUN_CODE'] : '1';
```

and that also did nothing.

**6.**...Cleared cache under var from *var/tmp* and *var/session*.

**Any help on what may be causing this issue would be much appreciated.**

Comment: Did you change the BASE URL in the admin prior to the domain change? Do you still have the old domain pointed there too?

Comment: No, I did not. I assume this could be changed from the DB?

Comment: Yes, if you look inside the table 'core_config_data' for your old domain name and change it to your new domain name it will help, remember to include a trailing slash

Comment: This did not correct the issue. This was the first thing I did initially, but nothing. Is there any other location that could hold the old domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**strong text**

First Open “Validator.php” file located as the following path. vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\Template\File\Validator.php

find the function :

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories)
```

Now inside this function find this line of code.

```
$realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
```

And replace this line of code with the below code.

```
$realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path));
```

Now compile your Magento by using commands:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: I only had to wait 9 years.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your stores domain name in the database.

Look at the table:

```
core_config_data
```

You should look for rows with path:

```
path = web/unsecure/base_url
path = web/secure/base_url
```

Update them to the new domain name, and then refresh your Magento cache, you can empty the /var/cache and /var/session directories.

Remember to include a training slash on your URL:

```
http://www.newdomain.com/
```

Comment: <code>[path]web/unsecure/base_url = [value](http://www.DOMAIN.com/)
[path]web/secure/base_url = [value]https://www.DOMAIN.com/</code>

I've changed them to this format, replacing domain for my new site url with still the same blank screen result. I have manually cleared the cache, as i cannot make use of the admin panel because it appears blank after logging in.

Comment: Is it just the main content area which is blank, does the navigation etc still work?

Comment: Is the frontend rendering ok?

Comment: `[path]web/unsecure/base_url = (http://www.DOMAIN.com/)
[path]web/secure/base_url = (https://www.DOMAIN.com/)`

I've changed them to this format, replacing domain for my new site url with still the same blank screen result. I have manually cleared the cache, as i cannot make use of the admin panel because it appears blank after logging in.

Comment: can you enable this in the index.php too, and see if you get an error message: ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Yes, I can see the header and footer for the admin panel. I can see the navigation options, and I can click on them. But the content area for the admin panel is not displaying anything.

Comment: Enabling ini_set('display_errors', 1); did not render anything :S